# Shader/other specific GPU calculation fails with different error messages - how to diagnoze further?

Tags: hardware-failure, gpu, bsod

I am having a very strange series of crashes on my PC and I wonder what can I do further to pinpoint the issue.

Crashes are almost exclusive to few GPU heavy applications, and in following software they manifest under 2 minutes of run constantly (I cannot make the apps run for more than 5 minutes), while other applications (also GPU heavy) seems to be unaffected at all.

So far I observed crashes at:

- FilterForge 13 (procedural art generator, not AI generative) - error *"Kernel::SystemException. Access violation"*
- Unity (game engine), but only during shader compilation step of final app (*"IPC error: failed to communicate with shader compiler process. Reason: shader compiler crashed. Please report a bug"*)
- Age of Wonders 4 (video game) - *"Game client crashed."*

These crashes manifest under 2 minutes of run, each of this app, each time. In case of Unity I observed it across five different versions of Unity Editor.

I also observed sporadic BSoD, last time at 1st December, WinDBG output follows:

```
SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (3b)
An exception happened while executing a system service routine.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000c0000005, Exception code that caused the BugCheck
Arg2: fffff8054d2d7dc7, Address of the instruction which caused the BugCheck
Arg3: ffffbe84e5c1da70, Address of the context record for the exception that caused the BugCheck
Arg4: 0000000000000000, zero.

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffbe84`e5c1e490 fffff805`4d2d7d83     : 00000000`00000000 ffff8000`a4802000 00000000`00000001 ffffffff`ffffffff : nt!ExpWakePushLock+0x37
ffffbe84`e5c1e4d0 fffff805`4d25c124     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000002 : nt!ExfTryToWakePushLock+0x23
ffffbe84`e5c1e500 fffff805`4d25bb0a     : fffff805`4dc69880 00000000`00000111 00000000`00000000 00000000`000000ff : nt!RtlpHpSegPageRangeAllocate+0x4c4
ffffbe84`e5c1e570 fffff805`4d2802f0     : 00000000`00000002 00000000`00001000 fffff8fc`7e3f1800 fffff805`4dc69880 : nt!RtlpHpSegAlloc+0x5a
ffffbe84`e5c1e5d0 fffff805`4d27fb3f     : 00000000`00001001 ffff9a0e`a62df0c0 00000000`6274624f 00000000`00000000 : nt!ExAllocateHeapPool+0x780
ffffbe84`e5c1e6f0 fffff805`4daac78d     : 00000000`00000100 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000401 00000000`00000000 : nt!ExpAllocatePoolWithTagFromNode+0x5f
ffffbe84`e5c1e740 fffff805`4d7160dd     : 00000000`00035000 fffff805`4d7160a0 00000000`00000010 00000000`00050286 : nt!ExAllocatePool2+0xdd
ffffbe84`e5c1e7f0 fffff805`4d71609b     : 00000000`00035000 00000000`000000d4 00000000`00000000 ffff9a0e`97ddc0c0 : nt!ExpAllocateTablePagedPoolNoZero+0x25
ffffbe84`e5c1e820 fffff805`4d715db2     : 00000000`00034c00 00000000`000000d3 ffff8000`6d1a5040 ffff9a0e`97ddc0c0 : nt!ExpAllocateLowLevelTable+0x17
ffffbe84`e5c1e850 fffff805`4d713adf     : 00000000`00000000 ffff9a0e`a62df0c0 00000000`0005b400 ffff9a0e`97ddc0c0 : nt!ExpAllocateHandleTableEntrySlow+0x56
ffffbe84`e5c1e890 fffff805`4d76f709     : ffff9a0e`97ddc0c0 ffff8000`53fad040 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!ExDupHandleTable+0xbf
ffffbe84`e5c1e960 fffff805`4d76d288     : ffff8000`6d1a5040 00000000`0002a800 ffffbe84`e5c1f270 00000000`00000000 : nt!ObInitProcess+0xa5
ffffbe84`e5c1e9c0 fffff805`4d774158     : 00000000`00000000 ffffbe84`e5c1f270 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!PspAllocateProcess+0xd98
ffffbe84`e5c1f1f0 fffff805`4d42b6e5     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffff9a0e`4a64e440 fffff805`4d6ee876 : nt!NtCreateUserProcess+0x778
ffffbe84`e5c1f9b0 00007ff9`eb9f0d44     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x25
0000009b`17d5d788 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ff9`eb9f0d44


SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!ExpWakePushLock+37

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.22621.2715

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0xffffbe84e5c1da70 ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  37

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  AV_nt!ExpWakePushLock

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {936a9116-626d-ff5b-6e91-6d53301ce50c}
```

I've already run MemTest (Windows 11) for 6 hours and vRAM MemTest ( https://github.com/GpuZelenograd/memtest_vulkan ), both gave no errors.

Hardware specs:

- Win11 Pro,
- Intel 13th gen, i9
- Asus Prime MoBo
- nVidia GeForce RTX series,
- 64 GB RAM

Comment: might want to try a CPU stress test. I think one can be gotten from intel directly, but unsure of its utility.

Comment: @Yorik Run SuperPI for a few hours. Nothing bad happen. I also run some other AAA games and also nothing bad happened...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okaaaay.

After looking for 3 long months, I finally found the solution.

Some Intel CPUs have hardware instability (most notable Intel 13900K and 14900K, less likely 13700, 14700) and this behavior will *mostly* appear when doing some very specific calculation (like mentioned shader compilation) so it will *not* show itself on Prime95 nor any known to me stress-testers.

## The solution

The solution proposed by Intel is to lower perfomance core multiplayer on CPU from 55x to 53x. Running on full power will make CPU make a very slight mistakes, that will accumulate quickly on shader compilation. They recommend using their own soft, called `Intel XTU` for that.

If you happen to have Asus Motherboard (like me), then `Intel XTU` will keep reverting your change to multiplayer after each reboot, as it cannot detect fail-safe watchdog on MoBo. There are many topics on the issue on Asus board, still unanswered from Asus support (mind you, some of these topics are only few days ago).

What will solve the issue definitely is to enter BIOS directly, change P-Core Multiplayer from `Auto` to 2 values lower than your defaults (check XTU, it will show you your standard values), then rebooting the PC.

The drop in performance is negletable, and stability is fully re-gained.

[Source that allowed me tracking this thing](https://www.radgametools.com/oodleintel.htm)